Openedx Getting WebpackBundleLookupError after clicking course in Card
I am upgrading the OpenEdX system from the native Koa version to the Tutor Palm version. The migration is almost 80% complete. All custom and native features are working, and the Course Studio part is functioning perfectly. However, I am unable to open courses in the LMS due to this error.

raise WebpackBundleLookupError(‘Cannot resolve bundle {0}.’.format(bundle_name))
webpack_loader.exceptions.WebpackBundleLookupError: Cannot resolve bundle CourseOutline.

Error due to this line super().get(request, course=course, page_context=page_context, kwargs)
course

<CourseBlockWithMixins @0E2D license=None, parent=None, name=None, tags=, display_name=‘Geography’, course_edit_method=‘Studio’, days_early_for_beta=None, due=None, edxnotes=False, edxnotes_visibility=True, giturl=None, graceperiod=None, graded=False, group_access={}, in_entrance_exam=False …

page_context

{‘course’: <CourseBlockWithMixins @0E2D license=None, parent=None, name=None, tags=, display_name=‘Geography’, course_edit_method=‘Studio’, days_early_for_beta=None, due=None, edxnotes=False, edxnotes_visibility=True, giturl=None, graceperiod=None, graded=False, group_access={}, in_entrance_exam=False, matlab_api_key=None, max_attempts=None, relative_weeks_due=None, rerandomize=‘never’, self_paced=False, show_correctness=‘always’, …

and for the native version of koa this object type is different this is Working
course

CourseDescriptorWithMixins(CombinedSystem(None, <xmodule.modulestore.split_mongo.caching_descriptor_system.CachingDescriptorSystem object at 0x7fe6faef9880>), InheritingFieldData(<xmodule.modulestore.split_mongo.split_mongo_kvs.SplitMongoKVS object at 0x7fe6facf7f40>), ScopeIds(user_id=None, block_type=‘course’, def_id=BlockUsageLocator(CourseLocator(‘RICE’, ‘10_10_2178’, ‘2021_Q1’, None, None), ‘course’, ‘course’), usage_id=BlockUsageLocator(CourseLocator(‘RICE’, ‘10_10_2178’, ‘2021_Q1’, None, None), ‘course’, ‘course’)))

page_context

{‘course’: CourseDescriptorWithMixins(CombinedSystem(None, <xmodule.modulestore.split_mongo.caching_descriptor_system.CachingDescriptorSystem object at 0x7fe6faef9880>), InheritingFieldData(<xmodule.modulestore.split_mongo.split_mongo_kvs.SplitMongoKVS object at 0x7fe6facf7f40>), ScopeIds(user_id=None, block_type=‘course’, def_id=BlockUsageLocator(CourseLocator(‘RICE’, ‘10_10_2178’, ‘2021_Q1’, None, None), …

Please let me know if anyone has faced this type of issue.

How did you upgrade? You cannot skip versions during the upgrade process.

The upgrade process follows a step-by-step progression through versions such as Koa, Lilac, Maple, Nutmeg, Olive, and Palm, involving MySQL and MongoDB version updates.

It feels like some package and static files issue because the tutor cannot run the collectstatic command.

tutor runs similar commands. In what version do you get this issue?

Tutor version 16.1.8 and OpenEdx version palm

The course content page is customized. I believe this issue is occurring because the "collectstatic" command is not working properly. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know so we can proceed accordingly.

Please follow these steps:
First check “/openedx/features/course_experience/static/course_experience/js/CourseOutline.js”
file exists or not. If not please add it. Because in Palm Edx this file is deprecated, so add from your code.
Then run simple commands in docker container:

tutor local exec lms bash
openedx-assets build
paver update_assets --settings=tutor.production

Openedx Discussion Forum (Openedx Getting WebpackBundleLookupError after clicking course in Card)
